# Sorting Categories by Parent then Sub

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pretty new to this but I have been trying to figure out how to sort categories by parent then child.
It automatically sorts alphabetically by default.
I changed the `orderby` in category-template to slug but it did not change on site.
Is there something else I need to change in theme? I'm using listingpro and I can see no options to fix this.